# Can't convert hh:mm string to hour in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have an original string field named "Hi" which I copied to an identical one Hi2 and then deleted (because I want the new one to be named "Hi").

The original "Hi" and "Hi2" are string fields that collect current hour with the following expression:

```
format_date(now(),('hh:mm'))
```

Although it works fine, I'd like to do the same but with a new date type field named "Hi" that includes the features of the previous field, but using

```
format_date(to_time("Hi2",'hh:mm'),'hh:mm')
```

returns a NULL value.

Sometimes the previsualization in the field calculator gives correct values (but the resulting field is empty) and sometimes returns de error

> Can't convert *11:17* to time]

[image]

How can I copy the original values to the new date type field?

Comment: No, you cant do that. Simply because the format you want is not a date, neither a time nor a datetime. hh:mm is just a string, nothing else.

Comment: It worked when converting a string dd/MM/yyyy to a date yyyy-MM-dd. I guessed it would be similar. Thanks.